# Accomplishment Viewer not displaying Ask Ubuntu badges

Tags: accomplishments

I've downloaded the new Ubuntu Accomplishment viewer. I've read and seen pictures of the program combining with AU badges. However, mine doesn't show anything other than the initial Trophies.

I've set up my identity with my launcpad email, and I've gone to File/Check Accomplishments and it still doesn't show any of the AU items. Is there something extra I have to do to get this program to work with AU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like you are running the 0.1 release of Ubuntu Accomplishments. You can check by clicking the About dialog in the Help menu. It should 0.1 in there.

Ask Ubuntu Accomplishments will be in the 0.2 release which comes out next week.